# What are the correct version numbers for react native?

Tags: react-native, mobile, version

What are the correct version numbers to `react-native`?

This question is primarily to aid those who are searching for an answer using an incorrect version number, e.g. `react-native 0.60` The hope is that anyone failing to find an answer with the wrong version number will find this question and then search again `react-native 0.60`. with the right version number.

I like to know to `react-native` developers experienced about the `version`.

> which version is better to use and doesn't will have problem for
>   linking and mismatch error to some other package.

Comment: Why do you think people should visit SO to find the answer? A simple search in google will link you to react-native documentation which has the updated version number. 

Comment: when you use react native, and packages for your project, you will get to much error because of mismatch error, some pkg will work to some version and some pkg will not be working to some version and because of that everytime have problem to link pkg and find match version for your project, my question was which version is more stable to working all or max pkg at react-native. yes everybody can find version in the react-native site and read the documentation. but I'm sorry when at this website don't write about developer experience. ;) @M.Hazara

Answer (score 1):

If i haven't misunderstand is 0.60. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the valid versions in react native documentation:

[React Native versions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/versions)

Answer (score 1):

you can find information here:
[link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60)